# Foreach loop mysql query

Tags: php

I have array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => 149
[1] => 150
)
```

how to make foreach loop and query ?
i like each of this $values to match result and return

```
$damasks = $cart['damask_id']; //array data
            foreach ($damasks as $key => $value) {

            }
```

**Complete Example:**

```
foreach ($damasks as $key => $value) 
{ 
    $damask_query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT oc_damask_name.name 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart 
        LEFT JOIN oc_damask_frontend ON ( $value = oc_damask_frontend.damask_id) 
        LEFT JOIN oc_damask_name ON ( oc_damask_frontend.damask_id = oc_damask_name.id ) WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' 
        AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' 
        AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'"); 
}
```

Comment: `echo $value;` will return 149 and 150, what kind of match result u have?

Comment: yes if i echo inside foreach will return both and if i do inside foreach query is returning only one value

Comment: share complete example,

Comment: foreach ($damasks as $key => $value) {
    $damask_query = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_damask_name.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart LEFT JOIN oc_damask_frontend ON ( $value = oc_damask_frontend.damask_id) LEFT JOIN oc_damask_name ON ( oc_damask_frontend.damask_id = oc_damask_name.id ) WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");
    }

Comment: `( $value = oc_damask_frontend.damask_id)` equal to column name?

Comment: yes but result is only 1 dont understand how to loop second $value and get result for both

Comment: which framework is it?

Comment: platform is opencart 3

Comment: print value inside the loop, you will get the both values, if you want to print outside the loop you must need to save values ni array

Comment: which variable giving u 1 value? `$damask_query` this?

Comment: yes if i print_r $damask_query result is only 1 value
how to store in array and loop it ?

Comment: `$damask_query` replace with `$damask_query[]` and print outside the loop `print_r($damask_query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example and comment, you are not storing data into an `array` and printing outside the loop, which will only print last index.

you need to store result into an array like: `$damask_query[]`

Example:

```
$damask_query = array(); // initialize
foreach ($damasks as $key => $value) 
{ 
    $damask_query[] = $this->db->query(" // change in this line
        SELECT oc_damask_name.name 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart 
        LEFT JOIN oc_damask_frontend ON ( $value = oc_damask_frontend.damask_id) 
        LEFT JOIN oc_damask_name ON ( oc_damask_frontend.damask_id = oc_damask_name.id ) WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' 
        AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' 
        AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'"); 
}

print_r($damask_query); // will print multiple records store in array.
```

Comment: now i get to another problem ... how to access them ?
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [num_rows] => 2
            [row] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test 6
                )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [num_rows] => 2
            [row] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test 7
                )
                )

Comment: solution is that, `foreach($damask_query as $newVal){ echo $newVal->name;}` @bobibobi

Comment: i face another problem if are only 1 item in cart this work fine but if is more than one all other items have the previews product damask look like its stack in that array any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: @bobibobi: please create a new question with this problem.